# Attack on challenge response protocol using shared symmetric key and addition of random nonce

Tags: authentication

Consider the following mutual authentication protocol, where KAB is a shared symmetric key. Give two different attacks that Trudy can use to convince Bob that she is Alice.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Crypto.SE. Please note that this is not a homework-solving service, so please tell us what you have tried to solve this task and where you got stuck, so that we don't have to repeat what you already know and we can tackle your actual problem instead of having to guess what it is.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because ["Do we accept basic level/homework questions? **Yes, we do.** However, … if you have just written out your assignment, your question will be closed.](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) Please edit your question accordingly so we can reopen it, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before that becomes science, you want to define what is success to Trudy and what's assumed impossible or otherwise off-limits given the context of the question. Consider:

- Sneaking in after the protocol
- Sneaking in early in the protocol and performing [MitM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack)
- Obtaining $K_\text{AB}$

  - enumerating many values of $K_\text{AB}$ (which can reveal $K_\text{AB}$) and checking if that matches intercepted data
  - more educated cryptanalysis of $E$
  - [side channel attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side-channel_attack)

    - on Alice
    - on Bob
  - otherwise getting $K_\text{AB}$ from Alice

    - bribery
    - [rubberhose cryptanalysis](https://xkcd.com/538/)
- Trying 42 as $E(R+1,K_\text{AB})$ and repeat ad nauseam
- Waiting till $R$ repeats
- Incapacitating Bob with a laser or other disturbance when he

  - chooses $R$
  - performs his check of $E(R+1,K_\text{AB})$

The list goes on.